# Specification for HTML to PDF conversion?

Tags: html, css, pdf

Is their any specific pattern or specific set of tags or css properties that should used in html to make it properly work in pdf format ?

For eg.

1. Does "float" property work in PDF?
2. Does "position" property work in PDF?
3. Is usage of "table" preferable over "div" in PDF?

Comment: Where did you read that PDF has any relationship with HTML? They're entirely different formats. They're probably more different than English and Sanskrit.

Comment: *HTML to PDF conversion* - which tool do you use for conversion?

Comment: This is a good question. Why isnt there a standard to render PDFs from HTML instead of using badly structured word documents to pdf.

Answer (score 2):

CSS doesn't work in PDF.

The elements and styles you use will depend on the software you use to transform the HTML+CSS into PDF, not anything that is intrinsic to PDF.